# Azure storage underlying technology

Tags: azure, storage, azure-storage

What is Azure storage made of, the underlying storage technology which supports the Azure storage we access in azure portal?

Is it object based storage or block storage (persistent/ephemeral) similar to categorization in Ceph?

If there is a mix of block and object based, which storage is used for each of exposed Azure storage service - block blob, append blob, page blob, storage tables, storage queues, Azure files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few years ago, Azure Storage team made a presentation about internals of Azure Storage at 23rd ACM Symposium on Operating Systems Principles (SOSP).

You can read more about this presentation here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/sosp-paper-windows-azure-storage-a-highly-available-cloud-storage-service-with-strong-consistency/.

Direct links:

Paper: http://sigops.org/sosp/sosp11/current/2011-Cascais/printable/11-calder.pdf

Video of presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnYdbQO0yj4

Powerpoint: http://sigops.org/sosp/sosp11/current/2011-Cascais/11-calder.pptx

Please go through this material. Hopefully it will give an idea about how Azure Storage is designed.