# Are Azure Blob copy operations cheap?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

Azure Blob Storage does not expose any kind of "blob rename" operation - which sounds preposterous because the idea of renaming an entity is a fundamental operation in almost any storage system - and Azure's documentation makes no reference to how a blob's name is used internally (e.g. as DHT key), but as we can specify our own names it's clear that Azure isn't using a content-addressable storage model (so renaming *should* be possible, once the Azure Storage team decides to allow it).

Microsoft advocates instead that to "rename" a blob, you simply copy it, then delete the original - which seems incredibly inefficient - for example, if you have a 200GB video file blob with a typo in the blob name - unless internally Azure has some kind of dedupe system - in which case it makes perfect sense to eliminate the special-case of "blob renaming" because internally it really would be a "name copy" operation.

Unfortunately the current documentation for blob copy ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/copy-blob ) does not describe any internal processes, and in-fact, suggests that the blob copy might be a very long operation:

> State of the copy operation, with these values:
>
> - `success`: the copy completed successfully.
> - `pending`: the copy is in progress.

If it was using a dedupe system internally then all blob copy operations would be instantaneous so there would be no need for an "in progress" status; also confusingly it uses "pending" to refer to "in progress" - when normally "pending" means "enqueued, not starting yet".

Alarmingly, the documentation also states this:

> A copy attempt that has not completed after 2 weeks times out and leaves an empty blob

...which can be taken to read that there are zero guarantees about the time it takes to copy a blob. There is nothing in the page to suggest smaller blobs are copied quicker compared to bigger blobs - so for some reason (such as a long queue, unfortunate outages, and so on) it could take 2 weeks to correct my hypothetical typo in my hypothetical 200GB video file - and don't forget that I cannot delete my original misnamed blob until the copy operation is completed - which means needing to design my client software to constantly check and eventually issue the delete operation (and to ensure my software runs continuously for up to 2 weeks...).

Is there any authoritative information regarding the runtime characteristics and nature of Azure Blob copy operations?

Answer (score 2):

As you may already know that `Copy Blob` operation is an asynchronous operation and all the things you mentioned above are true with one caveat. **The copy operation is synchronous when it comes to copying within same storage account**. Even though you get the same state whether you're copying blobs across storage accounts or within a storage account but when this operation is performed in the same storage account, it happens almost instantaneously.

So when you rename a blob, you're creating a copy of the blob in the same storage account (even same container) which is instantaneous. I am not 100% sure about the internal implementation but if I am not mistaken when you copy a blob in the same storage account, it doesn't copy the bytes in some separate place. It just create 2 pointers (new blob and the old blob) pointing to the same storage data. Once you start making changes to the blobs I think at that time it goes and changes those bytes.

For internal understanding of Azure Storage, I would highly recommend that you read the paper published by the team a few years ago. Please look at my answer here which has links to this paper: [Azure storage underlying technology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539498/azure-storage-underlying-technology/).